# Cannot read property 'DT_RowId' of undefined

Tags: laravel-5, datatables, serverside-datatable

I am calling API of 1 Laravel project to another Laravel project.

I am getting an following error:

> jquery.dataTables.min.js:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DT_RowId' of undefined

I have tried to provide offset and limit by default 0 and 10

```
$limit = 10;
$start =0;
```

Following is my project code

**Project 1**

```php
public function Jobe(Request $req)
{
    $columns = array(
        0 => 'jobid',
        1 => 'B',
        2 => 'C',
        3 => 'D',
        4 => 'E',
        5 => 'F',
        6 => 'G',
        7 => 'H',
        8 => 'I',
        9 => 'J'
    );

$limit = $req->input('length');
$start = $req->input('start');
$order = $columns[$req->input('order.0.column')];  
$sort['dir'] = $req->input('order.0.dir');
$job_pos_id = $req->get('Jobid');

$data = [
    'Job_pos_id' => $job_pos_id,    
    'start' =>$start,
    'length' =>$limit,
];

$payload = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, 
     CURLOPT_URL,"http:/localhost/PQWE/public/api/Api");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json', 
    'Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$payload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
$err = curl_error($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$totalData=$server_output[0];
$totalFiltered=$server_output[1];
foreach ($server_output as $acc)
{
    $nData['jobid'] = $acc['job_pos_id'];
    $data[] = $nData;
}

$json_data = array(
    "draw"            => intval($req->input('draw')),  
    "recordsTotal"    => intval($totalData),  
    "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalFiltered), 
    "data"            => $data,
    "count"           => $totalData,
);

return response()->json($json_data);
```

**Project 2**

```php
public function Api(Request $req)
{ 
    $limit = $req->input('length');
    $start = $req->input('start');
    $job_pos_id = $req->get('Jobid');

    if($job_pos_id == NULL) {
        $query = DB::connection('QWEERR')
        ->table('XYZ')->offset($start)->limit($limit)
        ->get()->toJson();

        $Totaldata= DB::connection('QWEERR')
        ->table('XYZ')->offset($start)->limit($limit)
        ->get();

    } else {
        $query = DB::connection('QWEERR')
        ->table('XYZ')->where('XYZ.jid','ILIKE', 
        '%'.$job_pos_id.'%')->get()->toJson();

        $Totaldata= DB::connection('QWEERR')
        ->table('XYZ')->where('XYZ.jid','ILIKE', 
       '%'.$job_pos_id.'%')->get();
    }

    $Total=count(Totaldata);
    Totalfiltered=$Total;
    return response()->json($query,Total,Totalfiltered);
}
```

Pagination error getting and at the time of search data not attaching error getting is:- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DT_RowId' of undefined

Comment: You have shown us so much code, but none of it includes `DT_RowId`.  It means this is not the code with the problem, and this is not what we need to see. You'll need to edit your question, delete the irrelevant code, and add the code causing the problem.  Please also try to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also note there are several places where you seem to have missed `$` for your variables, eg `Totaldata`, `Total`, etc. Those are probably not your current problem, but are problems.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting a very similar message with the latest DataTables.Net:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'DT_RowId')

I realised the **JSON** data source I was using had some **NULL items**.

In my code I was easily able to fix it by not returning any null items (that get serialized to Json):

```
return lists.Where(item => item != null).ToList();
```